# Shuffling random nos. in a combo box

Tags: vb.net

I use the following statement to shuffle the data in a range (for example 1 to 10) and result is stored in a combo box.

```
            Dim RndSQs As New Random()
            Dim ArNumbersSQs As Integer() = Enumerable.Range(1, Val(txtSQs.Text)).OrderBy( _

                       Function(x) RndSQs.Next()).ToArray()

            Dim iSQs = 0

            For iSQs = 0 To Val(txtSQs.Text) - 1

                cmbSQs.Items.Add(ArNumbersSQs(iSQs))

            Next iSQs
```

How can I shuffle that data which is already in a combo box but not in a range.  These nos. can be random no. that user shall chose.

Please guide.......

Comment: nos. is a standard abbreviation for numbers (and no. is number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to shuffle an array you could provide a custom sorter:

```
    Dim random As New Random()
    Array.Sort(elements, Function() As Integer
                               Return random.Next
    End Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, Val(txtSQs.Text))
```

Generates the range, and can be replaced by any IEnumerable.  For example, if you had a `List(Integer)` called `lst` of numbers, you could write:

```
lst.OrderBy(Function(x) RndSQs.Next()).ToArray()
```